# My websql insert sometimes works and sometimes fails without any error shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code , which sometimes inserts into the database and sometimes doesn't, i have a error handler too that needs to be triggered if insert fails , but no such thing occurs when insert fails , i am really stuck and have no idea what must be my next step , please help , and every time i get a message saying that the data has been inserted even though data has not been inserted

```
        db.transaction(function(transaction) {



    transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO expdtl_tmp(exp_date,hdr_id, category , title ,location , exp_ref, paid_to , pay_mode , tot_amount ,exp_amount ,tip_amount , oth_amount , exp_descr, odo_start ,odo_end , mileage ,  mileage_rate   )VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', [$('#date').val(), 0, loadcat_s, $('#title').val(), $('#location').val(), $('#reference').val(), $('#paid').val(), pay_m, $('#total_amount1').val(), $('#amout').val(), $('#tip').val(), $('#other_amount').val(), $('#description').val(), $('#odometer').val(), $('#stopodo').val(), $('#mileage').val(), $('#r_p_m').val()], expenselistinserted, errorHandler);



        });
```

I am using websql db , and no error is being shown

I even shortened my code , still its doing the same, please help

```
db.transaction(function(transaction) {
a= ('INSERT INTO expdtl_tmp(exp_date,hdr_id, category , title  , tot_amount)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)', [$('#date').val(), 0, loadcat_s, $('#title').val(), $('#total_amount1').val()]);
alert(a);
transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO expdtl_tmp(exp_date,hdr_id, category , title  , tot_amount)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)', [$('#date').val(), 0, loadcat_s, $('#title').val(), $('#total_amount1').val()], expenselistinserted, errorHandler);
});
```

Comment: When it doesn't insert what error are you getting?

Comment: do you have any idea why will it  not show the error